# Handling changing data in the Fact table

Tags: ssis

We have an employee & benefits data warehouse which is producing incorrect information in the fact table.

In File A (Feb), the employee has a leaving date of 27th Feb 2015.
In File B (Mar), the employee has a leaving date of 24th April 2015.
In File C (Apr), the employee has a leaving date of 24th April 2015.

The Employee dimension is correct.  We have an SCD which picks up the fact that the leaving date has changed and the record is updated.

The fact table is a daily grain, so when File A (Feb) is loaded, we have set the EmployeeLeftOnDay to true for the 27th.  The data for the 28th is now 0 because the employee is listed as leaving the company.  This is fine because our measures are not affected.

When we load File B (Mar), the Employee is active because the leaving date is now 24th April 2015, so we'll populate all of the data showing that employee is active between 1st March 2015 and 31st March 2015.

Now to File C (Apr), the employee is active up to the 24th April 2015 and on that date, the EmployeeLeftOnDay is set to true.  For the 25th April - 30th April, the employee will still exist, but will have 0.

The reason data appears after an employee has left is because they may appear in later files until their payroll is closed.  At this point they become inactive in the source application and won't exist in source files.

So when we test the "Leavers" measure, we get 1 more than expected, because this person, according to the flag, has left twice.

I should add that the fact table captures employee and benefit information, so assume the employee has 5 benefits (Healthcare, Dental, Pension, Childcare & Life Cover), so for each day, you'd have a 5 records per employee with the cost breakdown for the benefits.  In the scenario I described above, this means the 28th Feb has 0 for all costs to that employee's benefits.

Is there a clever way to do this besides having to write an update statement to *patch* the data?

Thanks!

Comment: Bob is hired, leaves. Returns but leaves again. That's a valid scenario (can happen a lot if it's union labor in the US at least) What should the leave count be? I think it's two leaves. Situations like that though, is why you can do a distinct count of employee leaves by ID. You'd fix your situation but the Bob situation would become incorrect. I'd argue that the count can only be as good as the data and since they did not get timely data or whatever shenanigans happened but we all know, you're still going to have to fix the data.

Comment: Situations like this, btw are why we ended up having to truncate and reload our HR model on a daily basis. They kept modifying business keys and telling us they had valid reasons for whatever nonsense they pulled

Comment: Hi, I agree with you there. We have a task to test for re-hires. That's part of the problem. The re-hire is a valid scenario as you point out, but this issue is either an admin error (entering the wrong leaver date) or the employee negotiated a later leaving date and it was then updated. In this scenario, the leave count should be 1 as the leave date was updated/extended by HR.